# Is it neccessary to use masonry on a div container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I am trying to use the Masonry javascript plugin.http://masonry.desandro.com/

Is it neccessary to have the container element as a div, couldn't it be something else? like article, etc?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened when you did?

Comment: Yes, I used the `<main id='something'>` as the parent container, with `article` as children. Did not work. It shows one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use any kind of container for masonry. However, it needs to be the main container for it to work correctly.

```
<article id='masonry'> // main container is article instead of div
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
</article>

var container = document.querySelector('#masonry');
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGCE7/) here